# What's the time complexity of this code with a branch?

Tags: python, math, time-complexity, big-o

```
def p(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    if b % 2 == 0:
        return p(a, b//2) * p(a, b//2)
    return a * p(a, b-1)
```

---

I know that it's O(n) if the code is:

```
def p(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    return p(a, b//2) * p(a, b//2)
```

However, when there is a `return a * p(a, b-1)` at the end, I'm not sure whether the time complexity will change.

Comment: Is there a reason for you not to store the result of `p(a, b // 2)` in a variable?

Comment: I'm convinced the time complexity is still O(b) (though I can't prove it yet); the main difference is that your 2nd code only returns 1, not a^b :) ; that said, as @InSync stated, calling p(a, b//2) only once would be more efficient (O(log(b)) if I'm not mistaken (`return (x := p(a, b//2)) * x` for example)

Comment: @InSync's question is important, because replacing `return p(a, b//2) * p(a, b//2)` with `x = p(a, b//2); return x*x` has a *profound* effect on the complexity of the function, and in fact the entire point of this algorithm is to avoid computing `p(a, b//2)` twice.

Comment: It still ends up being `O(n)` if it's linear.  That's a very valid point about efficiency but it doesn't change the time complexity.  If you care about the difference between the two, you're probably beyond pure python anyway and should be using a C library

Comment: @erik258: calling p(a, b//2) only once DOES change the complexity from O(b) to O(log2(b)).

Answer (score 2):

The complexity will not change, that is, both the algorithms' complexity is O(b).

It's obvious that the complexity depends only on b, so we just consider the size of b.

Consider the binary representation of b, it's length is log(b).

```
def p(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    return p(a, b//2) * p(a, b//2)
```

In the second code, every bit of b will multiply the total complexity by 2, so the final complexity is 2^log(b), i.e., O(b)

The first code can be viewed in the same way actually. If the current bit is 0, we multiply the complexity by 2. When the current bit is 1, the recursive call `a * p(a, b-1)` just flip the current bit from 1 to 0 and do the same thing again.

It may not be so strict, but the process apparently tells us that the two complexity is the same!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I did some maths, and you can prove (by a recurrence) that, when you call p(a,b), the total number of calls to p() is <= 3b - 1 for b >= 1, which indeed makes the time complexity O(b).

I won't give the full details, but the gist of it is that (calling N(b) the total number of calls to p()) : N(1) = 2; N(b+1) =  1 + N(b) if b is even and 1 + 2 * N(b/2) if b is odd. You can verify this, then do the recurrence.

Interestingly, the worst case scenario, where N(b) = 3b - 1, happens when b is a power of 2.

Comment: `b = 2**k` is the best case (since you always just divide by 2). I think you mean the worst case is `b = 2**k - 1`, where you are forced to alternate subtraction and division all the way to the base case (for example, 31 -> 30 -> 15 -> 14 -> 7 -> 6 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0).

Comment: No, in this case (where N(a, b//2) is called twice), 2**k is the worst case indeed; the fact it's the best case in an optimized algorithm is why I deemed this fact interesting.

Comment: Ah, OK, I was thinking about how it *should* have been implemented, not how it currently is.

Comment: Yes; I discovered it was the worst case while doing examples to prepare my recursion.